# Is it possible to test a scenario where many distinct users are logged in simultaneously in TestCafe?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am writing a web app where many distinct users will be logged in and interacting in real time. Is it possible to use TestCafe to test such a scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your specific needs, there might be some problems that are difficult to foresee now. However, TestCafe supports multiple browser windows, so it should be possible to use multiple windows where there are different users logged in each window.

Some details about that could be found in the documentation [here](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402841/guides/advanced-guides/multiple-browser-windows).

I always recommend trying out the chosen technology first on a few cases before going with it for good. You can pick out a few test frameworks like TestCafe and see what suits you best in your context.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen that part of the docs, but it wasn't clear to me if the cookies etc. are shared between windows. Also, I know TestCafe fairly well, so I'd prefer using it instead of learning a new technology (which would be great in and on itself, but the time for this project is a bit tight). Anyway, I'll just experiment...